# Firebase account linking error

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

So when you try to login to an app using some other auth method, for example at first the user used Google and now he using FB and those 2 accounts have the same mail, you get that error

> `auth/email-already-exists`

The thing is, that if you have 3+ auth methods, that error message isnt very specific and it could be a little tricky to develop a logic that handles this situation. How do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

email-already-exists is thrown in the firebase-admin sdk. I don't think it is thrown in the client SDK.
For the client SDK, the following errors would be thrown when linking an existing account to another one, or signing in with a new account where the email exists in another one:

- auth/account-exists-with-different-credential
- auth/credential-already-in-use
- auth/email-already-in-use

In all of the above, the error may contain the additional fields:

- error.email: The email for the associated credential you tried to sign in with
- error.credential: The credential itself (typically this is returned for OAuth credentials)

You can lookup the existing account to find out what providers exist for it:

```
firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail(error.email)
  .then(function(providers) {
    // Providers would be an array of the form:
    // ['password', 'google.com']
  });
```

For auth/account-exists-with-different-credential, you can then sign in with that provider and if needed link the error.credential to the signed in user.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.link(error.credential);
```

If the error occurred when linking (auth/credential-already-in-use), you can directly sign in with that credential

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(error.credential):
```